# Phone crash in android 4.0.3,why?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

**Recently I porting a phone project at platrom android4.0.3, when dialed a call, phone crash in incallscreen. The log as following**:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.phone/com.android.phone.InCallScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:823)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:729)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.ViewStub.inflate(ViewStub.java:232)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at com.android.phone.InCallScreen.initInCallScreen(InCallScreen.java:1223)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at com.android.phone.InCallScreen.onCreate(InCallScreen.java:514)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        ... 26 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.util.SparseArray.get(SparseArray.java:73)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:201)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1015)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:663)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1922)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1922)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:867)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:804)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1922)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:173)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1622):        at andro
W/ActivityManager( 1348):   Force finishing activity com.android.phone/.InCallScreen
```

thanks.
The erreo xml is:
*dtmf_twelve_key_dialer_view.xml line35: android:visibility="gone"*

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

                 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
                 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
                 You may obtain a copy of the License at

                      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

                 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
                 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
                 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
                 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
                 limitations under the License.
            -->

            <!-- Onscreen in-call DTMF dialpad.  This element contains the grid of
                 DTMF buttons (dialpad.xml) along with a TextView showing
                 the digits you've typed.

                 When the user presses the "Dialpad" button, this UI appears in the
                 upper part of the in-call screen, covering up the "call card" area.
                 The regular in-call controls (i.e. the InCallTouchUi widget) are
                 still visible at the lower part of the screen.

                 This layout is inflated in place of dtmf_twelve_key_dialer_stub
                 in incall_touch_ui.xml. -->
            <com.android.phone.DTMFTwelveKeyDialerView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/dtmf_twelve_key_dialer_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                android:visibility="gone"
                >

                <!-- Display of the digits you've typed so far.
                     This widget appears completely non-interactive to the user: you
                     can't edit or "hit backspace" since these are DTMF tones you've
                     already sent over the network.  But it's still an EditText rather
                     than a TextView because it needs to receive key events from a
                     hard keyboard, if present (see mDialerKeyListener). -->
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/dtmfDialerField"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:textSize="24sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:freezesText="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:textColor="@color/dtmf_dialer_display_text"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                    android:clickable="false"/>

                <!-- The dialpad itself -->
                <include layout="@layout/dialpad" />

            </com.android.phone.DTMFTwelveKeyDialerView>
```

Comment: InCallScreen.java the layout your are using go n check the line number 35 or post that layout xml file.

Comment: It should be taken to android enthusiasts 